# Cannot access javascript json properties?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object that has 4 MAKEs, 4 MODELs, 4 YEARs, 4 STATEs, 4 PLATEs, 4 COLORs properties:

```
Object {MAKE1="xxx ", MODEL1='xxx', YEAR1='xxx', STATE1='xxx', PLATE1='xxx', COLOR1='xxx', MAKE2='xxx', MODEL2='xxx' ,..., MAKE3='xx',..., MAKE4='xxx',...,COLOR4='xxx'}
```

my javascript:

```
 function displayPP() {
            $.getJSON('/ipad/api/formpp/' + personId + '/getmemberlatestpp', function(data) {

                for (var index=1; index<5; index++) {
                    $('#ppBody').append('<tr>');
                    var MAKE = 'MAKE' + index, MODEL = 'MODEL' + index, YEAR = 'YEAR' + index, STATE = 'STATE' + index, PLATE = 'PLATE' + index, COLOR= 'COLOR' + index;
                    var HTML = '<td>' + data.MAKE + '</td><td>' + data.MODEL + '</td><td>' + data.YEAR + '</td><td>' + data.STATE + '</td><td>' + data.PLATE + '</td><td>' + data.COLOR + '</td>';
                    $('#ppBody').append(HTML);
                    $('#ppBody').append('</tr>');      
                }                   
            });
    }
```

All the json properties returned as undefined. Why is that? if i do data.MAKE1, data.MAKE2 ... it works fine.

Comment: How do you expect to access `data.MAKE` when you have `MAKE1` ?

Comment: How would i access data.'MAKE'+index ?

Comment: I recommend using Fiddler to see the actual returns JSON.  If your using something like Microsoft technologies, a lot of the time the initial response is wrapped so you would actually have to do `data.d` to get the returned JSON.

Comment: (And duplicated countless times across SO in other questions, as high-rep users should know.)

Comment: You can see how to access it in the answers but this is ugly. You should have a different object for each car instead of having them all in one object with numbers behind. Example `Object {{"make":"xxx","model":"xxx"},{"make":"xxx","model":"xxx"}}` as @Quentin has suggested in his answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var foo = "X"; data.foo` will refer to the `foo` property, not the `X` property.

If you want to use a variable to represent a property name, then you have to use square bracket notation (which takes a string rather than an identifier).

```
data[foo]
```

---

That said, never have things which share a name save for a numeric counter on the end. Use proper data structures:

```
[ 
    { 
        "make": "xxx", 
        "model": "xxx", 
        "year": "xxx", 
        "state": "xxx", 
        "plate": "xxx",
        "color": "xxx"
    },
    { 
        "make": "xxx", 
        "model": "xxx", 
        "year": "xxx", 
        "state": "xxx", 
        "plate": "xxx",
        "color": "xxx"
    }
]
```

Comment: Don't know who downvoted. This is correct. `data[MAKE]` is what the OP is looking for. (Or at least data.MAKE1, whichever comes first)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i'm looking for. Will mark as solved when it's allowed.

Comment: I know but this table was poorly designed that way and I just need some quick data.

Comment: @DaveChen I downvoted because I thought that this was not relevant to the question but then it hit me so I withdrew my downvote and even upvoted `:P`

Answer (score 4):

You can access your properties using a string using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

`data['MAKE' + index]`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a variable like `MAKE = 'MAKE1'`, but you aren't actually using it when you use `data.MAKE`.  This will try to access a property named `'MAKE'` from `data`.  To lookup a variable from a string you need to use bracket notation, like `data[MAKE]`.

Here is the corrected version which replaces all of the incorrect dot property lookups:

```
function displayPP() {
    $.getJSON('/ipad/api/formpp/' + personId + '/getmemberlatestpp', function(data) {
        for (var index=1; index<5; index++) {
            $('#ppBody').append('<tr>');
            var MAKE = 'MAKE' + index, MODEL = 'MODEL' + index, YEAR = 'YEAR' + index, STATE = 'STATE' + index, PLATE = 'PLATE' + index, COLOR= 'COLOR' + index;
            var HTML = '<td>' + data[MAKE] + '</td><td>' + data[MODEL] + '</td><td>' + data[YEAR] + '</td><td>' + data[STATE] + '</td><td>' + data[PLATE] + '</td><td>' + data[COLOR] + '</td>';
            $('#ppBody').append(HTML);
            $('#ppBody').append('</tr>');      
        }                   
    });
}
```